# Persisting Arabic/Hebrew in MariaDB, received from webform

Tags: spring-mvc, apache-poi, mariadb

I have a small Spring 4 application that receives data from a form, persists it in MariaDB, displays it on a webpage and if asked returns the data written into an xls (MS Excel) document using Apache POI.
The application works fine for English text.

Here are the commands I ran to create and populate the db table:

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb COLLATE 'utf16_general_ci';
use testdb;
create table testtable( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,   text1 VARCHAR(100),   text2 VARCHAR(100),   text3  VARCHAR(200));
INSERT INTO testtable (text1,text2,text3) VALUES ('אבג','דהו','זחט');
```

Here is the JSP page for displaying and making requests:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-16">
</head>
<body>
<table border=1>
<tr><th>TEXT1</th><th>TEXT2</th><th>TEXT3</th></tr>
<c:forEach items="${rowList}" var="row">
    <tr>
        <td>${row.getText1()}</td>
        <td>${row.getText2()}</td>
        <td>${row.getText3()}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
<tr><td><br><form method="GET" action="/clear"><input type="submit" value="CLEAR TABLE" /></form></td>
<td><br><form method="GET" action="/getxls"><input type="submit" value="download XLS file" /></form></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<table border=1>
<tr><td>
<form method="POST" action="/add" accept-charset="UTF-16" >
<label>TEXT1</label>
<input type="text"  name="text1" /><br>
<label>TEXT2</label>
<input type="text" " name="text2" /><br>
<label>TEXT3</label>
<input type="text"  name="text3" />
<br>
<input type="submit" />
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the single controller for the application:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("rowList", userDao.getUserList());
        return "home";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/clear", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String clearTable(){
        userDao.deleteAllUsers();
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addCoding(
        @RequestParam("text1") String t1,
        @RequestParam("text2") String t2,
        @RequestParam("text3") String t3,
        ModelMap model
    ) throws Exception{
        User b = new User(java.net.URLDecoder.decode(t1,"UTF-16"), t2, t3);
        userDao.addUser(b);
        model.addAttribute("rowList", userDao.getUserList());
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getxls", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public void export1( HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException {
        List<User> users = userDao.getUserList();

        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

        // creating headers for data columns
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue("TEXT1");
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue("TEXT2");
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue("TEXT3");

        int rowIndex = 1;

        for(User user : users){
            row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(createHelper.createRichTextString(user.getText1()));
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(createHelper.createRichTextString(user.getText2()));
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(user.getText3());

            rowIndex++;
        } 

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=data.xls");

        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        wb.write(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

The data object in the controller is called `User` but it really is just and `int` for db id and three `String`s

Filling the form with the same Hebrew input as in the MariaDB console submitting it results in the following:
[image: Chromium request details]

[image: MariaDB select result]

[image: XLS file content]

In all of the three result displays, contents of line 1 and 3 are the same. (Or at least the input was)
Line 1 was entered using MariaDB console.
Line 3 was entered in the web page.
How can I process the web request so in the xls file lines 1 and 3 are the same?
Also how can I properly display data of line 1 on the web page?

Answer (score 0):

Correction to the JPS page:
1) adding

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

to the top of the document, this will properly display valid data pulled from the DB.

2) in the `<form>` rag, changing the value of attribute `accept-charset` from `UTF-16` to `ISO-8859-1`. This will return Arabic and Hebrew characters in the form of `&#xxxx;` where each `x` is a decimal digit.

Correction to logic - turning the said `&#xxxx;` characters into proper Arabic/Hebrew characters:
The hebrew 'Aleph' = 'א' passed as `&#1488;`.
In java `String.valueOf(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt("1488", 10)));` will return the proper 'א' character; so I added the following funcion to run on the input first thing in the controller:

```
    public static String y(String txt){

        String formatedString = "";
        char[] charArr = txt.toCharArray();
        for (int i=0; i<charArr.length; i++){
            if(charArr[i] != '&')
                formatedString += charArr[i];
            else {
                if (i+5 <= charArr.length && charArr[i+1] == '#'){
                    String temp = "";
                    for (int j=i+2;j<=i+5;j++)
                        temp += charArr[j];
                    if (temp.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")){
                        formatedString += String.valueOf(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt(temp, 10)));
                        i=i+6;
                    }
                } else
                    formatedString += charArr[i];
            }
        }
        return formatedString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use utf-16.  Use UTF-8, which is called utf8 or utf8mb4 inside MySQL.

The

On connecting you must specify the encoding in use by the *client*.

Columns in tables must be declared `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).

(Arabic and Hebrew are both handled.)

If you actually do have UTF-16 encoding at the client, then you can connect with utf16.  But I recommend using utf8 or utf8mb4 in the tables.  MySQL will convert on the fly.